# When I try and run get-pip.py it tells me "Successfully Uninstalled Pip"

Tags: python, pip

I've tried creating a new path too, I cannot for the life of me get pip to install. I am on windows 10 with Python 3.7. I'm new to this so excuse me if there is an obvious solution.

Comment: Can you provide a full dump of your shell after running the script?

Comment: Sounds like it worked. (It also probably wasn't necessary in the first place - pip should have been bootstrapped automatically without running get-pip.) The uninstall message should just be because it had to uninstall pip before performing the reinstall you ordered.

Comment: Yeah I missed that until just now, it's saying that its uninstalling because it "Found existing installation: pip 18.0"  and before the window closes it tells me "successfully installed: pip 18.0" but pip still doesn't work